# Returning a Derived Class Object from a function of the Base Type

Tags: c++, class, return, derived-class

Say i have three classes one called character, one ork and one human.
Human and ork are both derived from character.
Is there anyway to create a function of type character and inside that function be able to return objects created from either the ork or human classes. Or maybe there is another way of returning either ork or human objects from the same function.

Edit: Nevermind folks it turns out when i tried this earlier i accidentally derived ork and human from a different class. It is in fact possible to return a derived class from a function of base type.
Just to be clear this is what i was doing.

`character game::getPlayer(char symbol) {
    switch (symbol) {
        case 'E':
            return elfPlayer;
            break;
        case 'G':
            return guardPlayer;
            break;
        case 'K':
            return knightPlayer;
            break;
        case 'R':
            return roguePlayer;
            break;
        case 'W':
            return wizardPlayer;
            break;
    }
}`

Comment: Lookup the factory pattern.

Comment: For polymorphism and inheritance to really work, you need to use references or pointers. If you have a function which needs to create a child-class, it should return a pointer to the base-class.

Comment: @MikeMB: The "you can't" is wrong.

Comment: @MikeMB: Well, you can return it by value, no problem.

Comment: @Cheers: Isn't the derived type incomplete at the point where you would declare the member function of the base type and hence not a valid return type

Comment: @MikeMB: The derived type is incomplete at the point where you would declare the member function of the base type, and is a valid return type, as any incomplete type is. :)

Comment: Oh, did I say *any*? No no no. Not incomplete array type. Sorry.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Thanks. I don't know, why I assumed that incomplete tyes weren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  i  pictured  correctly  ,  u need  one  pure  virtual  function  inside  the base class  Character and  entire  function  would be  used  in derived  classes  in  Human  and Orc.

```
class  Character
{
   public: 
       Character();
    virtual ~Character();

    virtual  HRESULT  Characterfunc() = 0; 

private: 

}
```

and  then  in  derived  classes:

```
 class  Ork :  public Character
{
   public: 
         Ork();

  HRESULT Characterfunc();      

private:

}
```

And the last  one:

```
 class  Human :  public Character
{
   public: 
         Human();

  HRESULT Characterfunc();      

private:

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's first say you want to return a *value* of derived class, that's simple:

```
struct Derived;

struct Base { auto foo() -> Derived; };

struct Derived: Base {};

auto Base::foo() -> Derived { return {}; }
```

But with this approach, if `foo` is to return either a `Derived1` or a `Derived2`, then its return type must be the common base class of those two (or higher), and the result will then be sliced to that base class.

So for the multiple possible dynamic return types you need to return a pointer or a reference, e.g.,

```
struct Base
{
    auto foo() -> unique_ptr<Base>;
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

struct Derived1: Base {};
struct Derived2: Base {};

auto Base::foo()
    -> unique_ptr<Base>
{ return {garble_voff? new Derived1 : new Derived2}; }
```

When directly using a simple `unique_ptr` you need to have a virtual destructor in class `Base`, to support a simple `delete` expression.

Disclaimer: none of the code touched by a compiler.